# How to use function onOpen() when document creator's account was deleted and ownership was transferred?

Tags: google-apps-script

While researching the question, I learned that onOpen() always runs with the permissions of the document owner. In this case, the ownership was transferred and the original owner's account was deleted.

I could copy the document and sharing settings, rename it the same thing, delete the old one, and that would enable me to write some nice apps scripts. However, due to the nature of my job, deleting all the docs and making new ones might be frowned upon (even if I share them with the original people).

So, how can I ensure onOpen() runs as the CURRENT owner?

Comment: Did you delete the original script that was working and bound to the doc?  Or remove the `onOpen()` function from the script bound to the doc?

Comment: No, the script was working fine. I did not modify it, came back 5 days later and then onOpen() no longer functioned.

Comment: Take a look at the issue tracker for apps script at the following link:  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)